# Updated Mailbox Quota, Outlook does not update with new quota value

Tags: outlook, exchange-2013

My own mailbox on Exchange 2013 hit it's quota and outlook (2013) informed me of this, so I increased my Exchange mailbox quota.

Since increasing it, outlook has not updated to reflect this. I continue to be informed that I'm over my quota and I cannot send and receive.

Restarting outlook / my machine does not alter this. I changed it about 2 hours ago.

What can I do to force the refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjusting a few default values and restarting the information store did the trick. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684892(EXCHG.80).aspx

Comment: Hah...funny.  I was getting ready to say that the default is still 2 hours for the cached interval and was going to link that article as well.  Good job.